# Find near duplicate binary files (.lib,.bin)

Tags: algorithm, gcc, compiler-construction, diff, decompiling

Scenario is:
Though the source-code doesn't change, I'm seeing that the the compiled lib/bin files are having difference though It's compiled by same compiler and with same dependencies.

Since it's not a text file, I'm deprived of ideas, as we cannot use levenshtein distance, or pattern matching.

Another idea would be if, I'm able to add some salt to the source files, so that It is detectable in the compiled binaries?

Any ideas would be great, Since I have a huge no.of libs, I'm afraid it would be practically impossible for a Machine learning to be put in place.

Comment: Compilers put dates into object files. Linkers put dates into outputs.

Answer (score 3):

Use `objdump` to dump both binaries and compare the result with a text comparison tool. I don't know what sections you will need to check, but I would guess that the ones which change (and thus should not be included) are: .gnu.hash, .gnu_debuglink.

```
$ objdump -h /bin/sh

/bin/sh:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .interp       0000001c  0000000000400238  0000000000400238  00000238  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  0000000000400254  0000000000400254  00000254  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  0000000000400274  0000000000400274  00000274  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .gnu.hash     000036f8  0000000000400298  0000000000400298  00000298  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .dynsym       0000cbd0  0000000000403990  0000000000403990  00003990  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .dynstr       000083cf  0000000000410560  0000000000410560  00010560  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .gnu.version  000010fc  0000000000418930  0000000000418930  00018930  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  7 .gnu.version_r 000000b0  0000000000419a30  0000000000419a30  00019a30  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  8 .rela.dyn     000000c0  0000000000419ae0  0000000000419ae0  00019ae0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  9 .rela.plt     000012f0  0000000000419ba0  0000000000419ba0  00019ba0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 10 .init         00000018  000000000041ae90  000000000041ae90  0001ae90  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 11 .plt          00000cb0  000000000041aeb0  000000000041aeb0  0001aeb0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 12 .text         0008f088  000000000041bb60  000000000041bb60  0001bb60  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 13 .fini         0000000e  00000000004aabe8  00000000004aabe8  000aabe8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 14 .rodata       0001d790  00000000004aac00  00000000004aac00  000aac00  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 15 .eh_frame_hdr 00003cdc  00000000004c8390  00000000004c8390  000c8390  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 16 .eh_frame     00013a0c  00000000004cc070  00000000004cc070  000cc070  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 17 .ctors        00000010  00000000006dfe08  00000000006dfe08  000dfe08  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 18 .dtors        00000010  00000000006dfe18  00000000006dfe18  000dfe18  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 19 .jcr          00000008  00000000006dfe28  00000000006dfe28  000dfe28  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 20 .dynamic      000001b0  00000000006dfe30  00000000006dfe30  000dfe30  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 21 .got          00000008  00000000006dffe0  00000000006dffe0  000dffe0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 22 .got.plt      00000668  00000000006dffe8  00000000006dffe8  000dffe8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 23 .data         00008430  00000000006e0660  00000000006e0660  000e0660  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 24 .bss          00005b88  00000000006e8aa0  00000000006e8aa0  000e8a90  2**5
                  ALLOC
 25 .gnu_debuglink 0000000c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000e8a90  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

Comment: Can we get just the hash of a section ? for eg. .text .data or.bss etc ? The requirement is a fast analysis, Text diffing of huge binary code  will too time consuming ?

Comment: Go ahead. I just gave you the idea. Now you have to figure out how best to use it... Objdump itself does not provide just the hash, I don't think, but you could always look at their code to see how they did it and modify it to meet your needs.